# puppet-agent install not available from repo's on Debian Bullseye

Tags: debian, puppet, puppet-enterprise, bullseye

When I follow the instructions on Puppet docs and the `readme` at `https://apt.puppet.com/`, I download the correct deb package for my platform, install it with dkpg as per the instructions and it provides me with a sources file that points to a single repository providing puppetserver packages.

However, I already have a Puppet Server, I need to install puppet-agent on several clients in a lab environment. But the repository containing puppet-agent is not provided with the platform package.

More concrete, I downloaded and tried (one at a time, removing previous package), `puppet8-release-bullseye.deb`, `puppet-release-bullseye.deb`, `puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb`, `puppet7-release-bullseye.deb`.

I install the package with `dpkg -i puppetX-release-bullseye.deb` or `puppet-tools-release-bullseye.deb` and run `apt update` afterwards. As you can see in the link I provided for the readme, there is no `puppet-agent-release-bullseye.deb`.

The contents of the sources list files these packages install:

```
# Puppet 8 bullseye Repository
deb http://apt.puppet.com bullseye puppet8
# Puppet bullseye Repository
deb http://apt.puppet.com bullseye puppet
# Puppet Tools bullseye Repository
deb http://apt.puppet.com bullseye puppet-tools
```

I tried to be smart and simply add a file with this content:

```
# Puppet bullseye Repository
deb http://apt.puppet.com bullseye puppet-agent
```

But that didn't work ;)

Hence, the package puppet-agent is not available for installation using `apt install`.

I guess I could download the package with wget from `https://apt.puppet.com/pool/bullseye/puppet8/p/puppet-agent/puppet-agent_8.2.0-1bullseye_amd64.deb`, but then I still won't have a working repo and the package won't update.

Edit: The above won't work because the platform to install the agent on is arm, not x86_64.

Does someone know how I can get puppet-agent from a repository?

Thanks!

Comment: Having configured some version of the Puppet platform repository (via, say `puppet8-release-bullseye.deb`), the package you should be trying to install is named "puppet-agent".  Apt is not a native language for me, the the command would be something like `apt install puppet-agent`.  If an appropriate variation on that is not working then I would seek support from Puppet, Inc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ARM package for Debian bullseye, as can be seen by the lack of anything other than amd64 packages here:

http://apt.puppetlabs.com/pool/bullseye/puppet8/p/puppet-agent/index.html

There are also no packages at all for bookworm (no pool dir for this distro).

There is, however, ARM64 support for Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy):

http://apt.puppetlabs.com/pool/jammy/puppet8/p/puppet-agent/index.html

..as stated in the release notes for 8.3.1:

https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/release_notes_puppet#enhancements_puppet_x-8-3-0-PA-5050

This was released only yesterday (2023-11-07) and so was after your question was posed.

The full list of supported platforms is here:

https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/system_requirements.html#supported_operating_systems-packaged-platforms

Only RHEL and Ubuntu on ARM64 are supported (table cut down from the linked info) :

| Operating system | Tested versions |
| --- | --- |
| Red Hat Enterprise Linux, including: * Amazon Linux v1 (using RHEL 6 packages) * Amazon Linux v2 (using RHEL 7 packages) | 7, 8, 8 Power, 9, 9 (ARM64) |
| Ubuntu | 18.04, 18.04 AARCH, 20.04, 20.04 AARCH, 22.04 (x86_64, ARM64) |

So I would suggest moving to Ubuntu 22.04 for ARM64 support for Puppet 8, for now.